# Redirect_uri is cut in the middle, Spring boot, Nginx, Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, keycloak

I have deployed keycloak on docker, a spring boot application, all behind a nginx reverse proxy outside docker.
This is the path to protect: [www.example.com/oauth/test-idp](http://www.example.com/oauth/test-idp). The docker container is runned with `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`.
When I go on the resource is showed the login page to access to /idp, but the redirect_usi instead of: https%3A%2F%example.com%2oauth%2Ftest-idp (example.com/oauth/test-idp) is https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com2Ftest-idp (example.com/test-idp). Any solution?
this is my nginx configuration:

```
location ~ ^/oauth(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://11.11.11.11$1?$query_string;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

In my spring boot application I have this settings:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://example.com/auth/
keycloak.realm =realm
keycloak.ssl-required =external
keycloak.resource =resource
keycloak.credentials.secret =111111-111111-111111-1111
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] =role
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=test
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] =/idp

server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=X-FORWARDED-FOR
server.tomcat.protocol_header=X-FORWARDED-PROTO
```

Answer (score 0):

You strip the `/oauth` part form the request uri, this could cause some problem with redirects, as you observe with keycloak.

The best way to fix this is to use the same path between your spring boot app and the request sent through nginx.

If you really cannot do that, you can try to configure nginx to send the path in the `X-Forwarded-Prefix`, spring should be able to use it to build the correct redirect_uri with the property [`server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server).

This nginx conf may work (not tested) :

```
location ~ ^/oauth(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://11.11.11.11$1?$query_string;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /oauth;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }
```